# How to turn an Anorm RowParser[A] into RowParser[Option[A]]

Tags: mysql, scala, anorm

I use Scala Anorm for a project and I like to write parsers for case classes. I then reuse these parsers for other queries - typically when adding a `JOIN`.

Now sometimes, I expect an optional value (i.e. `LEFT JOIN` instead o of `JOIN`). It would be very handy to be able to reuse the same parser, any idea on how to achieve this?

As an example, say I have the following case class:

```scala
case class Specialty(
  id: Long,
  name: String
)
```

with the following parser:

```scala
def parser(table: String): RowParser[Specialty] = {
    get[Long]("id") ~ get[String](table + ".name") map {
      case id ~ name => Specialty(id, name)
    }
  }
```

How can I turn `parser:RowParser[Specialty]` into `parser:RowParser[OptionSpecialty]]`?

This would enable me to use it in a query where the table specialty is added through a `LEFT JOIN`.

As an extra piece of information, now I rewrite the parser like this:

```scala
def parserOptional(table: String):RowParser[Option[Specialty]] = {
    get[Option[Long]]("id") ~ get[Option[String]](table + ".name") map {
      case oid ~ oname => oid.flatMap{id =>
        oname.map{name =>
          Specialty(id, name)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384169/play-framework-using-anorm-rowparser), I think I found the answer

use `(parser ?)` or

```
def parserOptional(table: String):RowParser[Option[Specialty]] = parser(table) ?
```

Comment: "does not seem to work" does not seem to be precise (whereas `.?` combinator is covered by tests)